# how to set max amount of duplicate index in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

let's say I have this array :

> ```
> $array = [  
> {
>   "id": 3175,
>   "shape_id": 307,
>   "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257591914493",
>   "shape_pt_lon": "107.60664492839",
>   "shape_pt_sequence": 2,
>   "shape_dist_travel": "",
>   "jalur": "146-147",
>   "distance": 0.16133102419521
> },
> {
>   "id": 3180,
>   "shape_id": 308,
>   "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257591914493",
>   "shape_pt_lon": "107.60664492839",
>   "shape_pt_sequence": 2,
>   "shape_dist_travel": "",
>   "jalur": "147-146",
>   "distance": 0.16133102419521
> },
> {
>   "id": 3176,
>   "shape_id": 307,
>   "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257911430218",
>   "shape_pt_lon": "107.6069118082",
>   "shape_pt_sequence": 3,
>   "shape_dist_travel": "",
>   "jalur": "146-147",
>   "distance": 0.16415806438464
> },
> {
>   "id": 3179,
>   "shape_id": 308,
>   "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257911430218",
>   "shape_pt_lon": "107.6069118082",
>   "shape_pt_sequence": 1,
>   "shape_dist_travel": "",
>   "jalur": "147-146",
>   "distance": 0.16415806438464
> },
> {
>   "id": 3174,
>   "shape_id": 307,
>   "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257312336896",
>   "shape_pt_lon": "107.60638207192",
>   "shape_pt_sequence": 1,
>   "shape_dist_travel": "",
>   "jalur": "146-147",
>   "distance": 0.16421114665333
> } ]
> ```

how can I move those array to new array that only contain max two index that has the same value in shape_id.

so, the result I expected is :

```
    $array = [  
{
  "id": 3175,
  "shape_id": 307,
  "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257591914493",
  "shape_pt_lon": "107.60664492839",
  "shape_pt_sequence": 2,
  "shape_dist_travel": "",
  "jalur": "146-147",
  "distance": 0.16133102419521
},
{
  "id": 3180,
  "shape_id": 308,
  "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257591914493",
  "shape_pt_lon": "107.60664492839",
  "shape_pt_sequence": 2,
  "shape_dist_travel": "",
  "jalur": "147-146",
  "distance": 0.16133102419521
},
{
  "id": 3176,
  "shape_id": 307,
  "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257911430218",
  "shape_pt_lon": "107.6069118082",
  "shape_pt_sequence": 3,
  "shape_dist_travel": "",
  "jalur": "146-147",
  "distance": 0.16415806438464
},
{
  "id": 3179,
  "shape_id": 308,
  "shape_pt_lat": "-6.9257911430218",
  "shape_pt_lon": "107.6069118082",
  "shape_pt_sequence": 1,
  "shape_dist_travel": "",
  "jalur": "147-146",
  "distance": 0.16415806438464
}]
```

Please notice the last index array that have shape_id value = 307 did not copied because the new array aready have two object that have 307 earlier.

thank in advance !

Comment: That looks more like JavaScript than PHP...

Comment: i'm developing an API, so I use JSON inside my array.

Comment: Still, I'm not sure that's the proper way to go about it. PHP doesn't recognize JSON inside arrays natively. Have you tried running any code containing these arrays?

Comment: actually yes. I tried to draw polyline using that array in the map. but, i feels it take to long to load a whole data, so i decided to filter the array so that only contain max 5 index with the same shape_id. 

anyway, is that what you mean ? :D